# Calculate the set of autocorrelation functions and then sum them

Tags: matlab

Good evening! I have a 3D vector. It has the first dimension 1. For clarity, I set it exactly the same as used in my program. ***"с"*** is like a number of experiments, in this case there are three, so I calculate the correlation function three times and then add them up.

In fact, the number of experiments is 100. I have to calculate 100 correlation functions and add them.

Tell me how you can do it automatically. And if possible, then no cycles. Thank you.

And yes, in the beginning I set the 3D vector using a loop. Is it possible to set it without a loop as well? This is certainly not my main question, but I would also like to know the answer to it.

```
d = [1 2 3];
c = [4 2 6];

for i = 1: length(c)
   D(1,:,i) = d.*c(i);
end
D
X1 = xcorr(D(:,:,1));
X2 = xcorr(D(:,:,2));
X3 = xcorr(D(:,:,3));

X = X1+X2+X3;
```

With the help of a loop, my solution looks like this:

```
d = [1 2 3];
c = [4 2 6];
for i = 1: length(c)
D(1,:,i) = d.*c(i);
x(:,:,i) = xcorr(D(:,:,i));
 end
X = sum(x,3)
```

It seems to be correct. Is it possible to do this without a cycle?

Comment: just write a for loop that calculates the correlation, the same way you wrote a for loop that calculates `D` ? Its the same thing. Inside the for loop just do `X=X+xcorr....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily set your first array D without any loop, even though I don't know why you want to keep the first singleton dimension...

```
D(1, :, :) = d'.*c;
```

As for the sum of the autocorrelations, I'm not sure you can do it without a loop. The only thing that you can perhaps do is to not use an array to store the correlation for each index (if memory consumption is a problem for you) and just update the sum:

```
X = zeros(1, 2*length(d)-1); % initialize the sum array
for i = 1:length(c)
    X = X + xcorr(D(:, :, i)); % update the sum
end
```